# Magento: payment method "Heidelpay Credit Card" causes a delay of 180s in onepage checkout

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I was forced to move a legacy Magento 1.7.0.2 shop to another web hoster to keep support for PHP 5.3. (I know, everything is outdated, a relaunch is WIP but not yet ready for production.)

Now I face the problem, that the onepage checkout page has a delay of exactly 180 seconds (3 minutes). This happens when the customer starts the checkout and opens `/checkout/onepage/`.

I already checked fopen, curl, etc.
As it seems the connection to the payment provider doesn’t seem to be the problem as it arises already when I start the checkout process even before a payment solution is selected.

When I disable the payment method "Heidelpay Credit Card", the checkout works fast as before.

Any pointers how I can hunt down the problem? As far as I could trace the problem, it is within Magento and not the communication with the Heidelpay servers.

Answer (score 0):

I think any script of payment method takes time to get a response. Please check "async: false" is used in any ajax script or not?